# Apply min function in map2

Tags: r, purrr

I need to subtract values in one list from values in another list, both lists have lists in lists. It worked for me to apply the `map2` function. I am trying to apply `min (0,x)` to the function (makes the lowest number = 0), but I am not sure how to do this.

```
A1 <- list (aa = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))),
            bb = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))))

A2 <- list (aa = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))),
            bb = list(a = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15)),
                      b = data.frame(matrix(1:10,10,15))))

library(purrr)
map2(A1, A2, ~ map2(.x, .y, `-`))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmin`

```
map2(A1, A2, ~ map2(.x, .y,  ~ pmax(.x - .y, 0, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

or use a conditional logic

```
map2(A1, A2, ~ map2(.x, .y,  ~ {out <- .x - .y, 0
            case_when(out > 0 ~ out, TRUE ~ 0}))
```

Comment: In my example everything is 0 because the numbers are the same (sorry for the bad example), I tried to make the number different and get either 0 or NAs (also happen when I applied it to my real data)

Comment: @Shepard Not clear about your comment.  Are you saying this is not the expected

Comment: Sorry I might have stated not clear in my question. I expected if A1 - A2 > 0, returns the value, but if A1-A2 < 0, returns 0

Comment: @Shepard You need `pmax` instead of `pmin`

Comment: For the conditional logic, is there a typo in it? The `pmax` still produced several NAs in my data, but I will try to understand `map2` and figure out what happen and update here if I find the solutions.

Comment: @Shepard if there is NA, then you can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `pmax`.  The issue is with `-`, it returns `NA` if any of the values are NA i.e. `NA - 5` returns NA

Comment: my data has no NAs, but pmax returned several NAs. So it worked for some minus values to turn them to 0 but for some it returned NA.

Comment: @Shepard It wouldn't happen if there are no NAs because the NAs return only from the data

Comment: Without `pmax`, there are no NAs. I think I will need to understand the map2 function better first. Thank you so much!